# Intercept webapi json formatting errors

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to have a way to intercept the exception that occurs when you send in malformed json to a webapi endpoint, so that I can return a semantic error code as opposed to just 500. (e.g. "Fix your broken JSON or go to hell")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your custom validation filter attribute by deriving from [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext
                                     .Request
                                     .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                                                          actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you may either decorate your actions with it:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidationFilter()]
public string DoSomethingCool()
```

or register it globally via your `config`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ValidationFilterAttribute());
```

Comment: can this be done at a global level instead of having to decorate every method with the validationfilter attribute?

Comment: @user20358 Yes. Simply register the filter in `Global.asax.cs`: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidationFilterAttribute());`

Comment: Thanks. Should I be using ExceptionFilterAttribute or ExceptionHandler or MessageHandler. Which one is better?

Comment: Each one serves a different purpose. I suggest you snoop around google to see the differences between each of them.