# Validate id on HttpGet Request in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following web api:

```
public User Get([FromUri]string id)
```

Is there a way to validate that id to not exceed 10 characters before it executes the function? (I want it to work similar to a Model in a post request)

Comment: You can add `constraint` , but that is linked with `route`, check this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints, it says you can add constraint ,if input param length lies in certain range, like this `{x:length(1,20)}`

Comment: you could create a custom filter

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424404/intercept-webapi-json-formatting-errors/26425731#26425731)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The easiest way is to add the ASP.NET built-in Route Attribute to your method and add the constraint that match your requirements.
- You can build your custom constraint by implementing IRouteConstraint interface, like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints) example
- Also, you can create your own ActionFilterAttribute and decorate your method by this new attribute, and when your method executes your action filter attribute will be executed and with some validation rules, you can check your model and validate it or set an error in the response like in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424404/intercept-webapi-json-formatting-errors/26425731#26425731) that Yuval provides.